# Record F4V in Flash Media Server

Tags: ffmpeg, flash-media-server

I have problem with record live event in F4v through Flash Media Server
I publish my live event on FMS though FFMPEG
FFMPEG Code:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="A4TECH USB2.0 PC Camera" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 32k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 64k -ar 44100  -f flv rtmp://12.11.1.3/livepkgr/liveevent?adbe-live-event=liveevent
```

FMS Code to record F4V file:

```
var vodFile = Stream.get("mp4:" + StreamName.name + ".f4v");
vodFile.record();
vodFile.play(streamName,-1,-1);
```

So when I use -vcodec libx264 in ffmpeg FMS cam't to create F4V file, But when I erase -vcodec libx264 from FFMPEG FMS create F4V file currently.

Please advise me to solve this problem.

Comment: try removing the `-f flv`. According to ffmpeg documentation, that command forces it to be a flv, which is what you don't seem to want if you're making an f4v